# How does Linux execute command inside

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, operating-system

I was asked this question during an interview in Google, How does Linux/Unix execute your input command inside and what's the procedure?

I knew the shell didn't create a process for the command and use the shell process, but how does it work? does it different when we input a shell command like `cd` and a service like enable sshd `sshd start`?

Comment: Yes it’s quite different. `cd` is a built-in in many shell interpreters, so the action happens within the shell program (no kernel involved, except for reading directory contents, etc). For `ssh` (have you mentioned a startup script?) it goes much longer way.

Answer (score 0):

> I knew the shell didn't create a process for the command and use the shell process, but how does it work?

You must assume the shell creates a new process using `fork(2)` followed by `exec(3)`.  It happens the shell you are using have built-in commands, and then there is no new process in fact.  i.e., `time` in Bash does not execute `/usr/bin/time`, but its own implementation.

> How does Linux/Unix execute your input command inside and what's the procedure?

It is not clear to me what you mean by "execute your input command inside".  I will consider you are asking how the shell pass the parameter you typed in the command line to your program.

The complete command line of the program you are spawning lays on the new process stack.  Use `argv` pointer to reach it.  Each interleaved space is exchanged by `\0` which gives us an array of string(*). 
 `argc` is the size of this array.  Thus, the `main` prototype can be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

For more information [that is an excellent text about the stack layout in Linux](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html).

(*) an exception to this is when you use `\"`. Example:

```sh
$ echo hello world # broken into {"echo", "hello", "world"}
...
$ echo "hello world" # broken into {"echo", "hello world"}
...
```

> does it different when we input a shell command like cd and a service like enable sshd `sshd start`?

`cd` is commonly implemented as a built-in command; it just changes the working directory by invoking `chdir(2)`.  On the other hand, `sshd start` implies in `fork`+`exec` (see [GNU Libc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Creation-Concepts.html#Process-Creation-Concepts)).  `exec` at some point will set up the stack of the new process created by `fork` and assign the command line string to `argv`.